# JQuery onclick condition stop link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link:

Link

using::

```
$('#myID').click(function(){
    if($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Yes it is...'); //continue as normal
    }
    else {
        alert('Not checked');
        //exit do not follow the link
    }

...
```

so is //exit do not follow the link possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('#myID').click(function(e) {
    if ($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Yes it is...');
    }
    else {
        alert('Not checked');
        e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the standard link behaviour
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
$('#myID').click(function (e) {
    ...
} else {
    alert('Not checked');
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

You can also use `return false`, but this will also stop the propagation of the click event (which might be undesired).

Answer (score 3):

just use `return false;` when you want to stop the action at a specific point

Answer (score 2):

Return false in your else condition.

```
$('#myID').click(function(){ 
if($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")) { 
    alert('Yes it is...'); //continue as normal 
} 
else { 
    alert('Not checked'); 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Let your click-function receive the event as a parameter. Then you can do event.preventDefault() when you don't want to follow the link.

```
$('#myID').click(function(event){
   if($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")) {
       alert('Yes it is...'); //continue as normal
   }
   else 
   {
       alert('Not checked');
       //exit do not follow the link
       event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the event, and override the default behavior with the following:

```
$('#myID').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //exit do not follow the link
});
```